# Minimal NeoVim lua config for using nvim-cmp with lsp

Tags: lua, neovim, code-completion

I'm trying to write my own NeoVim Lua based config, stripped down to the minimum I need and with the goal to understand at least most of the config. LSP setup is working fine and is the only source I configured for nvim-cmp:

```
local cmp = require("cmp")                                                                                                                                                              
 
cmp.setup {                                                                                                                                                                             
  sources = {                                                                                                                                                                           
    { name = 'nvim_lsp' }                                                                                                                                                               
   }                                                                                                                                                                                     
}                                                                                                                                                                                       
local capabilities = vim.lsp.protocol.make_client_capabilities()                                                                                                                        
capabilities = require('cmp_nvim_lsp').update_capabilities(capabilities)
```

After some startup delay the completion is working in the sense that I see popups with proposed completions, based on information from LSP.

But I cannot select any of the proposed completions. I can just continue to type which reduces the proposed completions, but I cannot use tab, arrow keys, ... to select an entry from the popup. I saw in the docs that one can define keyboard mappings but cannot make sense out of them. They are all rather sophisticated, require a snippet package to be installed, ...

I would prefer to select the next completion via tab and to navigate them via arrow key. "Enter" should select the current one.

Could somebody show me a minimal configuration for this setup or point me to more "basic" docs?

Answer (score 5):

Nvim-cmp requires you to set the mapping for tab and other keys explicitly, here is [my working example](https://github.com/jdhao/nvim-config/blob/master/lua/config/nvim-cmp.lua):

```
local cmp = require'cmp'
local lspkind = require'lspkind'

cmp.setup({
  snippet = {
    expand = function(args)
      -- For `ultisnips` user.
      vim.fn["UltiSnips#Anon"](args.body)
    end,
  },
  mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.insert({
          ['<Tab>'] = function(fallback)
            if cmp.visible() then
              cmp.select_next_item()
            else
              fallback()
            end
          end,
          ['<S-Tab>'] = function(fallback)
            if cmp.visible() then
              cmp.select_prev_item()
            else
              fallback()
            end
          end,
          ['<CR>'] = cmp.mapping.confirm({ select = true }),
          ['<C-e>'] = cmp.mapping.abort(),
          ['<Esc>'] = cmp.mapping.close(),
          ['<C-d>'] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(-4),
          ['<C-f>'] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(4),
        }),
  sources = {
    { name = 'nvim_lsp' }, -- For nvim-lsp
    { name = 'ultisnips' }, -- For ultisnips user.
    { name = 'nvim_lua' }, -- for nvim lua function
    { name = 'path' }, -- for path completion
    { name = 'buffer', keyword_length = 4 }, -- for buffer word completion
    { name = 'omni' },
    { name = 'emoji', insert = true, } -- emoji completion
  },
  completion = {
    keyword_length = 1,
    completeopt = "menu,noselect"
  },
  view = {
    entries = 'custom',
  },
  formatting = {
    format = lspkind.cmp_format({
      mode = "symbol_text",
      menu = ({
        nvim_lsp = "[LSP]",
        ultisnips = "[US]",
        nvim_lua = "[Lua]",
        path = "[Path]",
        buffer = "[Buffer]",
        emoji = "[Emoji]",
          omni = "[Omni]",
      }),
    }),
  },
})
```

This is working great for me. The mapping part corresponds to the config for key `mapping` in the table. You can tweak your conf based on my config to make it work for you.